# GC Overhead limit exceeded because of a huge hibernate persist

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, garbage-collection

So I am having an issue that I read a CSV file with a lot of data, around a million entries and then I persist it in the Oracle DB and the application crashes because of the gc overhead limit error. From what I understand the crash happens because while the files are being stored they all stay in the heap, thus the gc can't clear them and eventually runs out of memory and crashes. Is there a way to improve this data persist so that the crash doesn't happen, without increasing the jvm memory? Perhaps splitting it into async methods or something, because I am running out of ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: For a mass load like that, I would recommend not using Hibernate, but use **JDBC** directly, utilizing the **batch** feature with occasional `flush()` of the batch buffer, e.g. every 1000 rows. Greatly improves performance, while minimizing the memory footprint. --- Reading the CSV file should of course use a **streaming parser**, to minimize the memory footprint.

Comment: Well I'm storing in batches of 1000 each time, unfortunately still doesn't help, what is the streaming parser btw?

Comment: A streaming parser will give you the rows as they are parsed from the file, instead of loading the entire file into memory and returning a `List`. There are many CSV parsing libraries for Java, some of them supports streaming, so pick one of those.

Comment: Alright will have a look, hopefully I can find something.